# Regex matching issue with re.escape

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to know what is wrong in my regex so that I can correct and match my string.I am using python 3.7

```
import re
a = '/hi/ji/hello/hello.log'

regex = rf".*\s+([\d]{4}-[\d]{2}-[\d]{2}\s+[\d]{2}:[\d]{2})\s+{re.escape(a)}"

line = r'-rw-rw---- hacluster  haclient      6889422 2021-07-22 17:53 /hi/ji/hello/hello.log'
y = re.fullmatch(regex, line)
if y:
    print(y.group(1))
```

Comment: There's no need to put `\d` inside `[]`.

Answer (score 1):

`{2}` in an f-string is replaced with just `2`. You need to double the `{}` to make them literal.

```
regex = rf".*\s+(\d{{4}}-\d{{2}}-\d{{2}}\s+\d{{2}}:\d{{2}})\s+{re.escape(a)}"
```

To debug this I did `print(regex)` and noticed all the missing `{}`.